# R - deliberately mask a function in a package function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to mask a function that a function from a package calls.

As a reproducible (I think) example, look at the function `isTRUE`:

```
function (x) 
identical(TRUE, x)
```

Suppose for some reason I wanted `identical` to *always* return `"foobar"`, and hence `isTRUE` would always return "foobar":

```
# try override identical
identical <- function(...) { return('foobar') }
identical(TRUE, 'a') # 'foobar', as expected
```

Now I call `isTRUE`, hoping that the call to `identical` in that function will access my *masked* version, but it doesn't:

```
isTRUE('a') # hope that this will return 'foobar'
# [1] FALSE
```

So in general, **how do I temporarily cause a function called from within a packaged function to return something different?**

#### Context

I have a function in my package:

```
myFunc <- function(...) {
    if (!require(rgdal)) {
        stop("You do not have rgdal installed")
    }
    # ...
}
```

I want to test that if rgdal is not installed, the function throws an error.
However, I do have rgdal installed. I want `myFunc` to think it isn't (temporarily), so I am trying to do:

```
require <- function(...) { return(FALSE) }
```

before calling `myFunc` hoping that it will fail. However, it appears that `myFunc` isn't tricked by this and still calls `base::require` instead of my `require`.

(Yes, this seems like a trivial thing, because most certainly `myFunc` would throw an error if I didn't have rgdal installed, but suppose now the condition were more complex and I wanted to test in the same way - my question still stands)

Comment: Just found a [question on the R mailing list](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e13/help/11/01/2443.html) that might be relevant, checking it out.

Comment: why not define `require` within the function -- would that be useful?

Comment: No. I only want to redefine `require` temporarily for the purpose of testing. Outside the testing, I wish `myFunc` to work as-is (with the usual `require`).

Comment: Partial solution: `assignInNamespace('somefunction', replacement, 'somepackage')` works if I am replacing a function within my own package, but not for `base::require` (which complains about being a locked binding, even if I use `unlockBinding`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programatically create a function

```
foo <- function(...) if(!require('MASS')) stop('foo')

testfun <- function(fun){
  require <- function(...) FALSE
  fff <- function(){}
    formals(fff) <- formals(fun)
    body(fff) <- body(fun)
  fff

}

testfoo <- testfun('foo')
```

`require` is defined as is `testfun` when the function is now created.

```
foo()
## Loading required package: MASS

detach(package:MASS)

testfoo()
# Error in testfoo() : foo
```

You could do something similar with `local`, but I think it would be messier

eg

```
testfoo2 <- local({
  require <- function(...) FALSE
  foo <- function(...) if(!require('MASS')) stop('foo')
  })

testfoo2()
## Error in testfoo2() : foo
```

---

(From mathematicalcoffee - a followup based on this answer).

I was able to define a function:

```
overrideIn <- function(f, ...) {                                                
    overrides <- list(...)                                                      
    nms <- names(overrides)[names(overrides) != '']                             
    # stub out the functions                                                    
    for (nm in nms) {                                                           
        assign(nm, overrides[[nm]])                                             
    }                                                                           

    # copy over f                                                               
    fff <- function () {}                                                       
    formals(fff) <- formals(f)                                                  
    body(fff) <- body(f)                                                        
    return(fff)                                                                 
}
```

so that I could do

```
f <- overrideIn(myFunc, require=function (...) FALSE)
```

Now when I call `f` it has the overridden version of `require` in it, so I can do (using the fantastic [testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html) package):

```
expect_that(f(), throws_error('You do not have rgdal installed'))
```

---

A slightly more succinct version of the overide function (mnel again)

```
overRideIn2 <- function(fun,...){
   e <- environment()
   .list <- list(...)
   ns <- nchar(names(.list))>0L

   list2env(.list[ns], envir = e) 

   fff <- as.function(as.list(fun))

  }
```

Comment: worked a charm, love it! thanks! never would have thought of that (I was going to keep playing around with `assignInNamespace`, I suspect futilely)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee -- i'm not sure how this will go if you are trying to overwrite a function within a function from another package where they have used `importFrom`

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with the same `overrideIn` trick that *mnel* and *mathematical.coffee* explained above and I ended up finding another alternative from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/emulating-dynamic-scoping-in-gnu-r/):

```
overRideIn3 <- function(fun,...){
    e <- environment()
    overrides <- list(...)
    ns <- nchar(names(overrides)) > 0L

    list2env(overrides[ns], envir = e) 

    environment(fun) <- e
    fun
}
```

Note that all of these dynamic scoping tricks only work on the scope of `fun`. That means that any helper functions that `fun` calls will not have access to the definitions provided in `overrides` unless `fun` also wraps those helper functions with `overRideIn`.